# how to invoke awscli from pip install?

Tags: command-line, python, path, aws, pip

Having [installed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21055859/262852) the AWS CLI with `pip install --user awscli` what's the syntaxt to invoke `awscli`?  It's listed here:

```
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ pip list
DEPRECATION: The default format will switch to columns in the future. You can use --format=(legacy|columns) (or define a format=(legacy|columns) in your pip.conf under the [list] section) to disable this warning.
adium-theme-ubuntu (0.3.4)
attrs (15.2.0)
awscli (1.11.35)
beautifulsoup4 (4.4.1)
botocore (1.4.92)
chardet (2.3.0)
colorama (0.3.7)
cryptography (1.2.3)
dnspython (1.12.0)
docutils (0.13.1)
enum34 (1.1.2)
futures (3.0.5)
gmpy2 (2.0.7)
greenlet (0.4.9)
html5lib (0.999)
idna (2.0)
iotop (0.6)
ipaddress (1.0.16)
jmespath (0.9.0)
lxml (3.5.0)
nglister (0.0.0)
PAM (0.4.2)
pip (9.0.1)
pyasn1 (0.1.9)
pyasn1-modules (0.0.7)
pyOpenSSL (0.15.1)
pyserial (3.0.1)
python-application (2.0.2)
python-dateutil (2.6.0)
python-eventlib (0.2.2)
python-gnutls (3.0.0)
python-msrplib (0.19.0)
python-otr (1.2.0)
python-sipsimple (3.1.0)
python-xcaplib (1.2.0)
PyYAML (3.12)
rsa (3.4.2)
s3transfer (0.1.10)
service-identity (16.0.0)
setuptools (32.3.1)
sipclients (3.0.0)
six (1.10.0)
Twisted (16.0.0)
unity-lens-photos (1.0)
wheel (0.29.0)
zope.interface (4.1.3)
thufi
```

thufir@doge:~$

per cdunklau on `#python` IRC:

```
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ ll .local/bin/aws*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 thufir thufir  814 Jan  2 00:06 .local/bin/aws*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 thufir thufir  204 Jan  2 00:06 .local/bin/aws_bash_completer*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 thufir thufir 1432 Jan  2 00:06 .local/bin/aws.cmd*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 thufir thufir 1135 Jan  2 00:06 .local/bin/aws_completer*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 thufir thufir 1915 Jan  2 00:06 .local/bin/aws_zsh_completer.sh*
thufir@doge:~$
```

Looking at the path:

```
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
thufir@doge:~$
```

I need to add `~/.local/bin/` to the path?

see also:

https://askubuntu.com/q/802544/45156

Comment: Is the directory that *pip* installs things when invoked as normal user in your ``$PATH``? Btw. you’ll probably fare better installing the ``awscli`` package from the distro you’re using.

Comment: probably so, but I've already started down this path, for possibly marginal increases in security, so will try to config it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solution:

```
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ tail .bashrc -n 1
export PATH="/home/thufir/.local/bin/:$PATH"
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ aws configure
AWS Access Key ID [None]:
```

Would've been much easier to just install with sudo.